# Consumer can't receive messages even though usePrefetchExtension is true

Tags: activemq-classic

If usePrefetchExtension is true(default), I think number of messages over prefetchSize are sent to a consumer.
I tried the following.

- ActiveMQ Version : 5.15.13
- activemq.xml :

```
  <policyEntry>
    <policyEntry queue=">" usePrefetchExtension="true" queuePrefetch="1">
  </policyEntry>
```

- consumer.sh options :

```
  --ackMode CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE
  --batchSize 10
  --sleep 10000
```

After 100 messages are sent from a producer, consumer.sh is executed.
I think 10 messages (=batchSize) are sent to a consumer.
But, after one message is sent, any other messages aren't sent.
The following is shown at Active Consumers Menu of web console.
Do I misunderstand the meaning of usePrefetchExtension?

- Enqueues : 1
- Dequeues : 0
- Dispatched : 1
- Dispatched Queue : 1

Comment: What does the consumer actually do?  It isn't clear from your question what behavior you are seeing on the consumer itself

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  
I use the [following example consumer](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-console/src/main/resources/org/apache/activemq/console/command/consumer.txt).  

After consumer is executed, the following logs are shown. First messages can be  received. But other messages can't be received.

 INFO | consumer-1 Received ID:XXXX-1:1:1:1:1